# jquery breaking on site upload via ftp

Tags: javascript, jquery, ftp

When I amend or edit one of our sites pages via ftp, the Javascript on the entire site breaks. I believe this is because strange characters appear in the JS core file of JQuery.js despite this starting as a working file.

If a external freelance developer uploads to the site it works fine.

Already tested different ftp software and bypassing the server when uploading.

This happens on multiple sites. Can any provide any solutions to what might be causing this?

strange code in JQuery.js as below and in attachment.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvOSR.png)

(" "+c.className+" ").replace(ac," "):" ")){f=0;whi¿‹8¿‹8Ä⁄7Pÿ7(›8‡‹8ûF‡‹8,removeClass:

Comment: Can I provide any more information to make this more answerable?

Comment: I've tested out different software and location so I believe this is to do with wither php or hosting if anyone has come across a similar situation before. I know the web file works on a different domain